# An application of Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

> Show that an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ has a sequence of vectores $x_n$ and a sequence of bounded linear functionals $l_n$ such that $||l_n||=||x_n||=1$ for each $n$ and $l_n(x_m)=1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ if $n\neq m$.

So, by taking $x_1\neq 0$ in $X$ and $Y_1=$span $\{x_1\}=\{ax_1|a\in \mathbb{C}\}$, the linear functional $l_1$ where $l_1(ax_1)=a||x_1||$ has an extension that satisfies $||l_1||=||x_1||=1$ (This is by Hahn Banach Theorem). So now $l_1(x_1)=1$. Next I was going to take $x_2$ as a point off of $Y_1$ and do the same. But now how do we know that $l_1(x_2)=0$?

Comment: Pick $x_2\neq0$ in the null space of $l_1$.

Comment: Isn't null space of $l_1$ trivial here?

Comment: I think that the null space of $l_1$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: How? If $a||x_1||=0$ then $a=0$

Comment: Null space considered as $l_1 : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $l_1$ were a function from X to R how do you define the null space?

Comment: Missed that you consider spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, so then the null space is considered as $l_1: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Usual definition for null space: $\{ x \in X : l_1 (x) = 0\}$.

Comment: It might help to consider the finite dimensional case.  Suppose $\textrm{dim}X=n<\infty$, and let $L$ be a linear functional on $X$.  Since the range of $L$ is $1$-dimensional, the rank-nullity theorem tells us that the dimension of the null space is $n-1$.  Now consider $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok got it thanks

Comment: Now I take $Y_2=$ span of $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and define $l_2(ax_1+bx_2)=b||x_2||$ to get $l_2(x_1)=0$. But now how should I pick $x_3$? If we pick it from the intersection of null spaces of $l_1$ and $l_2$ then done, but how do we know the intersection is non empty?

Comment: $\ell: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $\ell(x) = (l_1(x),l_2(x))$.